# How append live search results from ajax call in Google style?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax live search function that successfully returns the values it needs to return. But I simply need to list the results like Google or Youtube, which I can't figure out how to do it(this is my first time making a live search function).
So I need to the values to return simply like this:

[image]

here is my current index page code:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search">
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="prefix button">

<ul id="searchresults" class="searchresults"></ul>
```

Here is my ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#s').typeWatch({
    captureLength: 2,
    callback: function(value) {

       $.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "searchq", s : value},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               $.each(response.val,function(){
                  var li = $('<li/>').appendTo('#searchresults');
                  $('<a/>').text(this.post_title).attr('href',this.url).appendTo(li);       
               });
            }
          },
          error: function(errorThrown) {
          }
      })
   }
});//end typewatch event

});
```

This will return the results like so:
[image]

The result does appear in a list but it's not the same as google or youtube, where you can scroll through it with your arrow keys.

When I click in the input form in the second image, I get the standard dropdown displayed over it which is exactly how I want the results to display(but this only displays what I typed previous).

So my question is how do I get my results in there, or create that?

I hope this is clear enough to understand what I'm trying obtain.

(I chose to not include php function since that 100% works like it's supposed to)

Comment: Google does a dynamic autocomplete, whereas you create a <ul> list and append it to a div.
check this out: 
https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

Comment: Do not put the results in a `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the autocomplete attribute of the textual input to "off" to disable previously entered text from appearing in a dropdown. For example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

A review of the autocomplete attribute is provided at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autocomplete.asp).